# Rx INotifyPropertyChanged to IObservable<Tuple<TProperty,TProperty>>

Tags: c#, system.reactive, inotifypropertychanged

This must be a case of poor googling on my part as I know I saw a solution for this out on the wbe before, but how would I go about implementing an extension method which is able to convert `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` events into an `IObservable<Tuple<TProperty,TProperty>>` where the values of the tuple represent the oldValue and the newValue of the property?

**So I want to know what is the best way to take something like this:** ([credit for below to](http://www.robfe.com/category/net/system-reactive/))

```
public static IObservable<TProperty> ObservePropertyChanged<TNotifier, TProperty>(this TNotifier notifier,
    Expression<Func<TNotifier, TProperty>> propertyAccessor,
    bool startWithCurrent = false)
    where TNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    // Parse the expression to find the correct property name.
    MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)propertyAccessor.Body;
    string name = member.Member.Name;

    // Compile the expression so we can run it to read the property value.
    var reader = propertyAccessor.Compile();

    var propertyChanged = Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
        handler => (sender, args) => handler(sender, args),
        x => notifier.PropertyChanged += x,
        x => notifier.PropertyChanged -= x);

    // Filter the events to the correct property name, then select the value of the property from the notifier.
    var newValues = from p in propertyChanged
                    where p.EventArgs.PropertyName == name
                    select reader(notifier);

    // If the caller wants the current value as well as future ones, use Defer() so that the current value is read when the subscription
    // is added, rather than right now. Otherwise just return the above observable.
    return startWithCurrent ? Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Return(reader(notifier)).Concat(newValues)) : newValues;
}
```

**And convert it to fit this signature:**

```
public static IObservable<Tuple<TProperty,TProperty>> ObservePropertyChanged<TNotifier, TProperty>(this TNotifier notifier,
    Expression<Func<TNotifier, TProperty>> propertyAccessor,
    bool startWithCurrent = false)
    where TNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    // Parse the expression to find the correct property name.
    MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)propertyAccessor.Body;
    string name = member.Member.Name;

    // Compile the expression so we can run it to read the property value.
    var reader = propertyAccessor.Compile();

    var propertyChanged = Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
        handler => (sender, args) => handler(sender, args),
        x => notifier.PropertyChanged += x,
        x => notifier.PropertyChanged -= x);

    // Filter the events to the correct property name, then select the value of the property from the notifier.
    var newValues = from p in propertyChanged
                    where p.EventArgs.PropertyName == name
                    select reader(notifier);

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**Edit:** I figured out something that seems to work after trying many different operators. Is this a correct way of accomplishing this? Is there anything I'm missing?

```
public static IObservable<Tuple<TProperty,TProperty>> ObserveValueChanged<TNotifier, TProperty>(this TNotifier notifier,
    Expression<Func<TNotifier, TProperty>> propertyAccessor,
    bool startWithCurrent = false)
    where TNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    var observable = ObservePropertyChanged(notifier, propertyAccessor, startWithCurrent);

    return observable.Scan(new Tuple<TProperty, TProperty>(default(TProperty), default(TProperty)),
                    (acc, p) => new Tuple<TProperty, TProperty>(acc.Item2, p));

}
```

**Edit:** I incorporated Gideon's solution to end up with the following:

```
public static IObservable<Tuple<TProperty, TProperty>> ObserveValueChanged2<TNotifier, TProperty>(this TNotifier notifier,
    Expression<Func<TNotifier, TProperty>> propertyAccessor,
    bool startWithCurrent = false)
    where TNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    // Compile the expression so we can run it to read the property value.
    var reader = propertyAccessor.Compile();

    var newValues = ObservePropertyChanged(notifier, propertyAccessor, false);
    if (startWithCurrent) {
        var capturedNewValues = newValues; //To prevent warning about modified closure
        newValues = Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Return(reader(notifier))
                                .Concat(capturedNewValues));
    }

    return Observable.Create<Tuple<TProperty, TProperty>>(obs => {
        Tuple<TProperty, TProperty> oldNew = null;
        return newValues.Subscribe(v => {
                if (oldNew == null) {
                    oldNew = Tuple.Create(default(TProperty), v);
                } else {
                    oldNew = Tuple.Create(oldNew.Item2, v);
                    obs.OnNext(oldNew);
                }
            },
            obs.OnError,
            obs.OnCompleted);
    });
}
```

*P.S.
I eventually stumbled upon my current solution, but I don't want to violate any etiquite for SO, should I add an answer or close the question (I'd prefer not to delete since this may prove useful later)? I'm still not sure this is the best way of doing this*.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged does not give you access to the old value.  I don't think this event is a good fit for what you are trying to do

Comment: I remember there being a discussion somewhere about using ReplaySubject to capture the values. So I thought I can capture the initial value somehow and then always show a staggered window of the old value and the current/new value. Does that make sense? I just don't know how to do it in Rx.

Comment: I would create a custom event and make life easy.

Comment: One thing to note is that by way of the property expression of this extension I can get access to the value at the time of subscription and at the time of subsequent event firings. Can't I use an Rx operation to essentially queue up 2 then fire?

Comment: I'm not trying to sound like a jerk, but if you already know what to do, why are you asking the question?  If you have an idea, try it, then come back when you get stuck.

Comment: I'm asking the question because I am not very familiar with Rx. Don't know if I need to do Merge, Join, Window, Buffer or use some other operator to do what I want to do. I am attempting to try to solve as well, but my lack of experience is my hurdle. I was hoping someone with experience could help.

Comment: The information you seek isn't available in INotifyPropertyChanged, but there are a few custom solutions. ReactiveObject from ReactiveUI has this functionality. Maybe that's what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to existing operators, `Zip` along with `Skip` would probably be the closest to what you need.  I would probably write it myself like this (picking up where you throw the NotImplemented):

```
if (startWithCurrent)
{
    newValues = Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Return(reader(notifier))
                          .Concat(newValues));
}

return Observable.Create<Tuple<TProperty, TProperty>>(obs =>
    {
        Tuple<TProperty, TProperty> oldNew = null;
        return newValues.Subscribe(v =>
            {
                if (oldNew == null)
                {
                    oldNew = Tuple.Create(default(TProperty), v);
                }
                else
                {
                    oldNew = Tuple.Create(oldNew.Item2, v);
                    obs.OnNext(oldNew);
                }
            },
            obs.OnError,
            obs.OnCompleted);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Something like this is precisely what I was looking for.